# Collect different dimensional data in a loop

Tags: matlab

I wanna collect data in a loop, for example

```
for k = 1:10
   A=magic(randi(5));
   ...
end
```

now I wanna collect A data for each iteration.
thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you want to store `A` at each iteration? In a 3D matrix? A cell array? A structure? Be more specific on how you want the data saved.

Comment: I've tried to  save it in a matrix or cell array, but I couldn't. I think a dynamic structure could solve it but don't know how can I fill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can save this data and store it in a single variable.  Because your data can vary in size at each iteration, you can choose either a cell array or a structure to save your data.

If you elect to use a cell array, something like this could work:

```
k = 10;
A = cell(k, 1);
for idx = 1 : k
    A{idx} = magic(randi(5));
end
```

We create an empty cell array of `k` elements and we populate each cell at each iteration of the loop.  Using `A{i}` will access the data found at the iteration `i`.  You may also elect to use a structure where each field would be a string based on the iteration number.  Something like this could work:

```
k = 10; 
A = struct();
for idx = 1 : k
    A.(['data' num2str(idx)]) = magic(randi(5));
end
```

This will create `k` fields in the structure `A` where each field is data from an iteration.  You can access the data at iteration `i` by doing `A.datai`.